# Compiling Hadoop Examples in Mac

Tags: macos, hadoop

I am new to Unixlike operating systems.
After installing Hadoop as per the instructions below,
http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/Running_Hadoop_On_OS_X_10.5_64-bit_(Single-Node_Cluster)

I am trying to build the examples as given in the same URL using
ant examples

This gives me an exception as below

compile-mapred-classes:
Trying to override old definition of task jsp-compile
    [javac] /Users/hadoop/hadoop-1.2.1/build.xml:549: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds

create-native-configure:

BUILD FAILED
/Users/hadoop/hadoop-1.2.1/build.xml:634: Execute failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "autoreconf" (in directory "/Users/hadoop/hadoop-1.2.1/src/native"): error=2, No such file or directory

What exactly is needed for my Mac to get past this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As the error says, you need to install `autoreconf`. The easiest way to do it is through [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) (`brew install autoconf`, after you install the Homebrew itself).

Incidentally, `hadoop` can be installed through Homebrew as well.

Comment: Thank you. It helps. I get another error as the compilation proceeds - create-native-configure:
     [exec] Can't exec "aclocal": No such file or directory at /usr/local/Cellar/autoconf/2.69/share/autoconf/Autom4te/FileUtils.pm line 326.
     [exec] autoreconf: failed to run aclocal: No such file or directory. Appreciate your help.

Comment: ``aclocal`` is a tool from ``automake`` package (``brew install automake``). Not sure why it is not a dependency.

Comment: Thanks Again. It helped to proceed. However now another one     [exec] configure.ac:48: error: possibly undefined macro: AC_PROG_LIBTOOL
     [exec]       If this token and others are legitimate, please use m4_pattern_allow.
     [exec]       See the Autoconf documentation.

Comment: I used brew install libtool and now I have built all the examples successfully. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue, and was able to resolve it by installing automake, autoconf and libtool:

```
brew install automake autoconf libtool
```

Answer (score 3):

Running a couple of brew unlink {formula} && brew link {formula} on automake, autoconf and libtool did the trick for me